# Upload image File from file path

Tags: android, image, file, kotlin, resources

In android studio I have uploaded an image to the drawables folder in resources and not I'm trying to use that image in my project. Im checking to make sure the image file exists, but checking if it exists returns false everytime

```
        val imgFile = File("/Users/jakesmith/Desktop/Attachments/app/src/main/res/drawable/myimage.png")

        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.absolutePath)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
        }
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is in `drawable` folder, use `R.drawable.myimage` with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`.

Answer (score 0):

This can perform what you want in Java code.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage)
```

If you want to do it in layout file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sampleimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/myimage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` as mentioned in comments. And then simply use try catch to avoid ResourceNotFound exception.

```
val image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.myImage)
imageView.setImageBitmap(image)
```